# RDFS/OWL Model Restriction

Tags: owl

I am going through some questions on RDFS/OWL models, and have to infer some triples based on a model. However, I haven't seen the restriction in this model, at least a restriction written like this.

```
:John :worksAt :companyA
:John rdf:type :employee
:John rdf:type [∃⩽1 owl:onProperty :worksAt]
```

My understanding of this is along the lines of "An employee must have at least one :worksAt", or in other words `owl:minCardinality` of 1.

Comment: no, that's not correct. It just holds for the individual `:John` here that 1) he is an `:employee` and 2) he `:worksAt` at least 1 Thing and 3) he `:worksAt` some entity called `:companyA` - there is not any general statement nor can you infer anything new

Comment: that said, your syntax is strange, it's a mix of RDF triples and Description Logic syntax.